# How to connect MariaDB with Grails?

Tags: grails, mariadb

I need to link a second database to my system (I have one in grails) and I am not finding the way, what I am using is the following:

```
dataSource_maria {
 dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
 driverClassName = 'org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver'
 username = 'root'
 password = 'greenArrow2019'
 url = 'jdbc:mariadb://192.168.0.20/db'
 dbCreate = 'validate'
}
```

Console Error:

```
| Error 2019-03-18 11:06:40,695 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
Message: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    Line | Method
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1149 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    624 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    748 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that you're including the JDBC driver for Maria in your project.  For example, in a Grails 3 build.gradle file you could add a dependency on

```
compile 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:2.4.1'
```

If you are including the JDBC driver and still getting a class not found exception, please update this question with your build info and grails version so people can help you further.

Comment: FYI info on Maria driver versions can be found here among other places: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing issues connecting to a mariadb database and I am using grails v3.3.11, mariadb v10.4.13 and java 1.8.

Firstly, that dialect does not exist for hibernate.  See the [org.hibernate.dialect](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/ackage-summary.html) package for available dialects. A common one used is the `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect`, which worked fine for me.

Secondly, you need to add the mysql connect dependency `runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.48'`

In application.yml you can configure something similar as below to successfully establish  connection to the mariadb database

```
pooled: true
jmxExport: true
dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/mozstart
username: root
password: ''
```